# Not working, How to push random variables to array and output total of array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

First function produces a random number. Each time the second function is called it should output the total number of array values added together. why does this only output one variable value?

```js
function random() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}

var addtime = [];
function totalArray() {
  var newCell3 = random();
  var Value = '';
  var total = 0;

  value = newCell3;
  addtime.push(value);

  for (var i in addtime) {
    total += addtime[i];
  }

  console.log(total);
}

totalArray();
```

Comment: Because you pushed only one number in the array?

Comment: How would you push a new random number every time the function is called?

Comment: Because you are printing the sum of the elements, which in this case is the only random element pushed

Comment: Rather, you called `totalArray();` just once

Comment: Okay hypothetically the function was called 10 times, so 10 random numbers should be added to the array and the total of this array should be output

Comment: Well hypothetically it would display the total of your array, but in reality it was called once, so it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```js
const random = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

var addTime = [];

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', totalArray);

function totalArray() {
  const newValue = random();
  let total;

  addTime.push(newValue);

  total = addTime.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);

  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you really helpful answer.